# how or where wordress collect unlogged user session

Tags: customization, theme-development, multisite, users

i see the pattern in some theme where we can collect session of unlogged user. for example, in a comment form: After user commenting, user can see that the their comment is waiting for a moderation.

i want to know in what hook (the file, the class, or the functions) we can collect the information.

fyi i'm need this information to extaned theme capability to handle unlogged user. For example show them 'message' that they need register before submitting something or uploading something.

Answer (score 1):

unlogged users do not come with nothing. so it's easy: no-where. for the comments scenario you describe, wordpress creates cookies. cookies are fairly well integrated with PHP, you can find out more about that part of PHP here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php

Have fun!